# Perl: Removing array items and resizing the array

Tags: arrays, perl, array-difference

I’m trying to filter an array of terms using another array in Perl.  I have Perl 5.18.2 on OS X, though the behavior is the same if I `use 5.010`.  Here’s my basic setup:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
#use strict;
my @terms = ('alpha','beta test','gamma','delta quadrant','epsilon',
             'zeta','eta','theta chi','one iota','kappa');
my @filters = ('beta','gamma','epsilon','iota');
foreach $filter (@filters) {
    for my $ind (0 .. $#terms) {
        if (grep { /$filter/ } $terms[$ind]) {
            splice @terms,$ind,1;
        }
    }
}
```

This works to pull out the lines that match the various search terms, but the array length doesn’t change.  If I write out the resulting `@terms` array, I get:

```
[alpha]
[delta quadrant]
[zeta]
[eta]
[theta chi]
[kappa]
[]
[]
[]
[]
```

As you might expect from that, printing `scalar(@terms)` gets a result of `10`.

What I want is a resulting array of length 6, without the four blank items at the end.  How do I get that result?  And why isn’t the array shrinking, given that the [perldoc page about `splice`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/splice.html) says, “The array grows or shrinks as necessary.”?

(I’m not very fluent in Perl, so if you’re thinking “Why don’t you just...?”, it’s almost certainly because I don’t know about it or didn’t understand it when I heard about it.)

Comment: `grep` operates on arrays and returns matching elements. Maybe you mean `$terms[$ind] =~ /$filter/` to match a single one?

Comment: Yep, looks like that works as intended—thanks!  I’m still confused about why the array didn’t shrink with what I was doing before.

Comment: It's always tricky to remove elements from an array you're actively iterating over. That shifts the offset by 1 each time you splice something out.

Comment: FWIW, [`use VERSION`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/use.html) only specifies the _minimum_ version needed; it doesn't emulate the Perl interpreter as it existed at that version.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can always regenerate the array minus things you don't want. `grep` acts as a filter allowing you to decide which elements you want and which you don't:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;

my @terms = ('alpha','beta test','gamma','delta quadrant','epsilon',
           'zeta','eta','theta chi','one iota','kappa');
my @filters = ('beta','gamma','epsilon','iota');

my %filter_exclusion = map { $_ => 1 } @filters;

my @filtered = grep { !$filter_exclusion{$_} } @terms;

print join(',', @filtered) . "\n";
```

It's pretty easy if you have a simple structure like `%filter_exclusion` on hand.

**Update**: If you want to allow arbitrary substring matches:

```
my $filter_exclusion = join '|', map quotemeta, @filters;

my @filtered = grep { !/$filter_exclusion/ } @terms;
```

Comment: That one only partly works—it filters out `gamma` and `epsilon`, but not `beta test` or `one iota`.  Useful to have on hand for future projects, though!

Comment: Added a version that tests arbitrary substrings. This one uses a regular expression again, but just one test per entry, not N tests.

Comment: Cool, thanks!  That does indeed work.  Mind you, I have no idea whatsoever how or why it works.

Comment: `grep` acts like a pass-fail filter on each element in `@terms` here, so for a given `$_` from `@terms` it tests if it matches that pattern or not. The pattern is just a regular expression that matches any one of them as substrings.

Answer (score 0):

To see what's going on, print the contents of the array in each step: When you splice the array, it shrinks, but your loop iterates over 0 .. $#terms, so at the end of the loop, $ind will point behind the end of the array. When you use `grep { ... } $array[ $too_large ]`, Perl needs to alias the non-existent element to `$_` inside the grep block, so it creates an `undef` element in the array.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw{ say };

my @terms = ('alpha', 'beta test', 'gamma', 'delta quadrant', 'epsilon',
             'zeta', 'eta', 'theta chi', 'one iota', 'kappa');
my @filters = qw( beta gamma epsilon iota );

for my $filter (@filters) {
    say $filter;
    for my $ind (0 .. $#terms) {
        if (grep { do {
            no warnings 'uninitialized';
            /$filter/
        } } $terms[$ind]
        ) {
            splice @terms, $ind, 1;
        }
        say "\t$ind\t", join ' ', map $_ || '-', @terms;
    }
}
```

If you used `$terms[$ind] =~ /$filter/` instead of `grep`, you'd still get uninitialized warnings, but as there's no need to alias the element, it won't be created.

Comment: @ikegami: I don't see `gamma` in the output. Moreover, this is not a "fix", it should only demostrate WHY and WHEN the trailing elements are created - therefore, they're still there.

Comment: @ikegami: If I `print "@terms"`, I see `alpha delta quadrant zeta eta theta chi kappa`.

Comment: Oh sorry, the bug happens if you start with `@terms = qw( gamma gamma kappa );`. The second gamma gets moved into `$terms[0]`, which isn't revisited.

Comment: @ikegami: True, you're right. But I was just trying to explain why the undefs exist.